# DATEDIFF - Replace NULL with NOW()

Tags: mysql, date, datediff

I got following SQL Query

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    c.name,
    e.location,
    e.designation,
    e.time_period_from,
    e.time_period_to,
    DATEDIFF(e.time_period_to, time_period_from) AS tenure_in_days
FROM
    employment e
LEFT JOIN
    company c ON (c.id = e.company_id)
LIMIT
    0, 10
```

This is working perfectly, i have a scenario where `time_period_to` can have `NULL` values, in this case, i want to replace it with current date.

Here is what i tried.

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    c.name,
    e.location,
    e.designation,
    e.time_period_from,
    e.time_period_to,
    DATEDIFF(IF(ISNULL(e.time_period_to), NOW(), e.time_period_from)) AS tenure_in_days
FROM
    employment e
LEFT JOIN
    company c ON (c.id = e.company_id)
LIMIT
    0, 10
```

This gives me the following error

```
ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: `DATEDIFF(e.time_period_to, time_period_to)` -- that will always be `0`, since you're subtracting a time from itself.

Comment: No, It returns me NULL

Comment: It will return `NULL` if the column is `NULL`. But when the column is filled in, it will return 0 because you're subtracting the column from itself.

Comment: Shouldn't you subtract a start time from an end time to get a valid difference?

Comment: Like `DATEDIFF(time_period_to, time_period_from)`?

Comment: The `MySQL` function [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) does exactly what the title of your question says (*"replace `NULL` with ..."*).

Comment: I store NULL values, @Barmar regarding the column you are right, let me update it here.

Comment: Thanks @axiac i missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` instead:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    c.name,
    e.location,
    e.designation,
    e.time_period_from,
    e.time_period_to,
    DATEDIFF(COALESCE(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from) AS tenure_in_days
FROM employment e
LEFT JOIN company c ON (c.id = e.company_id)
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I guess you wanted `DATEDIFF(e.time_period_to, e.time_period_from)`.

Using `LIMIT` without explicit `ORDER BY` may return result dependent on execution plan.

Comment: I wanted opposite `DATEDIFF(e.time_period_to, e.time_period_from)` let me check this.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Easy to fix, just replace `_from` and `_to` suffixes. Let me know your final query.

Answer (score 2):

You have your parentheses in the wrong place. Instead of specifying `e.time_period_from` as the second argument to `DATEDIFF`, you have it as the third argument to `IF`. It should be:

```
DATEDIFF(IF(ISNULL(e.time_period_to), NOW(), e.time_period_to), e.time_period_from) AS tenure_in_days
```

You can also use `IFNULL` (which is a simpler version of `COALESCE`, and the name is more mnemonic):

```
DATEDIFF(IFNULL(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from) AS tenure_in_days
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, makes a lot of sense.