# DATEDIFF if a value IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, datediff

This is a follow-up of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525443/datediff-replace-null-with-now) which i posted earlier.

I am calculating the SUM of DATEDIFF using following syntax

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(COALESCE(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from)) / COUNT(DISTINCT e.company_id)
```

What i want now is to calculate `SUM` of `DATEDIFF` only if `e.time_period_from is NOT NULL`

I tried following query.

```
SUM(IF(e.time_period_from IS NOT NULL), DATEDIFF(COALESCE(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from), 0) / COUNT(DISTINCT e.company_id)
```

This gives me SQL syntax error.

How to go about it ?

UPDATE :

Here is my full MySQL Query

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.email,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(question_id)) as number_of_answered_questions,
    (SELECT option_id FROM answer WHERE user_id = u.id GROUP BY option_id ORDER BY COUNT(option_id) DESC LIMIT 1) as option_id,
    SUM(IF(e.time_period_from IS NOT NULL), DATEDIFF(COALESCE(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from), 0) / COUNT(DISTINCT e.company_id) AS tenure_in_days
FROM
    user u
LEFT JOIN
    role r ON (r.id = u.role_id)
LEFT JOIN
    answer a ON (a.user_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN
    employment e ON (e.user_id = u.id)
WHERE
    r.slug = 'app_user'
GROUP BY
    u.id
LIMIT
    0, 10
```

As you see this is for a sub select i cannot put a where condition outside of it.

And here is the error i get.

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), DATEDIFF(COALESCE(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from), 0) / COUNT(D' at line 1"
```

Thanks.

Comment: i think you just got the brackets wrong, IF has 3 parameters, first the condition, 2nd the value if condition is true, and 3rd the value if it is false. but your bracket closes after the condition

Comment: @VipinJain Let me update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in my comment before i think you just set brackets wrong what you want to get is this:

```
SUM(IF(e.time_period_from IS NOT NULL, DATEDIFF(COALESCE(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from), 0))
/ COUNT(DISTINCT e.company_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

i check your query 
error in this line

```
 SUM(IF(e.time_period_from IS NOT NULL), DATEDIFF(COALESCE(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from), 0)
```

use this instead above line code

```
 SUM(IF(e.time_period_from IS NOT NULL, DATEDIFF(COALESCE(e.time_period_to, NOW()), e.time_period_from), 0));
```